# How to do error correction after encoded Bell measurement?

Tags: error-correction, bell-basis

Need some help with the concepts of encoded/logical bell measurement.

Please visualize the picture in your mind. Suppose I have a node with 7+7 qubits side by side, left 7 is $|0_{L}\rangle$ and right 7 is $|+_{L}\rangle$. Suppose $|0_{L}\rangle$ = $|1001011\rangle$ and $|+_{L}\rangle$ = $|0011011\rangle$. Now I apply $CNOT$ between each pair of left and right qubits and after that $H$ gate on the all left side 7 qubits.

Now the problem how do I error correction. This part I am having confusion. I have an idea but I am having doubt.

Do I need to take additional 7 qubits for the left side and apply $CZ$ on each one and similarly additional 7 qubits for the right side and apply $CX$? This idea came after seeing the bell measurement from teleportation. This part is bothering, since those are logical qubits.

Comment: How come $|+_L\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|0_L\rangle$? They should have an inner product of $1/\sqrt2$. Also, how do these states relate to whatever error correcting code you're wanting to use?

Answer (score 0):

Well, You should know Logical qubits are having topological feature.
those are not spanning in a single state like you said.

Logical qubit has to be written in superposition states. like this.
this is arbitrary state for shor code with distance 3.

[image]

and if you are wondering about CNOT operation between two Logical qubits read this paper.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4022